# How do I sort an array full of null Values WITHOUT using Comparator?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, insertion-sort, compareto

this is my first post. As you can guess, this is a related homework question but I am having some trouble on this topic because others have been able to use Comparators to compare null objects to eachother, I cannot. Here is my code:

This is where the string is declared and located

```
public class OrderedStringArrayList {

    private String[] array;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public OrderedStringArrayList() {
        array = new String[10];

    }
```

This is the actual sort

```
 public int insert(String item) {
        boolean arrIsOpen = false;
        //------------------------Insert Sort Vars---------------------------
        int parseOne = 0;
        int parseTwo = 0;
        int reaLen = array.length;
        String check = "";
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            /*---------------------------------------------Check for Open slot-----------------------------------------------*/
            if (array[i] == null) {
                arrIsOpen = true;
            }
            if (arrIsOpen == true) {
                array[i] = item;
                break;
            }
        }
            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if (arrIsOpen == true) { //Insert Sort here

            for (parseOne = 1; parseOne < (reaLen); parseOne++) {
                check = array[parseOne];

                parseTwo = parseOne - 1;
                while (parseTwo >= 0 && ((check.compareTo(array[parseTwo]) < 0))) {
                    array[parseTwo + 1] = array[parseTwo];
                    parseTwo--;
                }
                array[parseTwo + 1] = check;
            }
        }
        else {                  // Grow the array by factor of 2 and copy over elements
            String[] backingArray = new String[2 * array.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                backingArray[i] = array[i];
            }
            /*----------------------------------------------------------------------Sort--------------------*/
            reaLen = backingArray.length;
            for (parseOne = 1; parseOne < (reaLen); parseOne++) {
                check = array[parseOne];


                parseTwo = parseOne - 1;
                while (parseTwo >= 0 && (check.compareTo(array[parseTwo]) < 0)) {

                    array[parseTwo + 1] = array[parseTwo];
                    parseTwo--;
                }
                array[parseTwo + 1] = check;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and here is the test

```
    @Test
    public void insertOneItem() {
        OrderedStringArrayList a = new OrderedStringArrayList();
        assertEquals("Size should be 0 after construction!", 0, a.size());
        a.insert("Hello!");
        assertEquals("Size should be 1 after one insert!", 1, a.size());
    }
```

My error occurs on the second code block on this line:

```
while (parseTwo >= 0 && (check.compareTo(array[parseTwo]) < 0)) {
```

I get a NullPointerException because check == null and its trying to compare. Thing is,  I cannot use comparators to sort this. My end goal is to place an item in this array, grow it by 2 if there is no room. In order to check if there is room, there needs to be an empty (null) spot in my string array, but I cannot compare anything to the null spot so I cannot sort the array. This has been bugging me for days please help.

EDIT: Here is the Stacktrace / Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at OrderedStringArrayList.insert(OrderedStringArrayList.java:57)
    at OrderedStringArrayListTests.insertOneItem(OrderedStringArrayListTests.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace. You do *not* get a NPE from comparing to a `null` value.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: You're confusing two completely different operations, insertion and sorting.  I assume that the idea was to keep the array always sorted by inserting any new value in the right spot.  So think of it as 2 discrete steps:  1. Check if the array has room.  If not, allocate a new, larger array and copy all the contents.  2.  Find the right spot  to insert your new value.  Working from the end, shift everything from the end to the insert point one place down.  Then insert.  (Note that in the code you posted, when you do have to copy, you never do the actual insert.)

Answer (score 0):

If your array content count is 1, it is already sorted, it is a special case where you don't go over your sorting mechanism

```
public class OrderedStringArrayList {

   private String[] array;
   private int arrayContentCount = 0;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public OrderedStringArrayList() {
       array = new String[10];

    }
}

public int insert(String item) {

   if(arrayContentCount == 0) { <--- this
         //insert the item and be done with it.
     array[0] = item;
     arrayContentCount++;
     return;
   }
    boolean arrIsOpen = false;
    //------------------------Insert Sort Vars---------------------------
    int parseOne = 0;
    int parseTwo = 0;
    int reaLen = array.length;
    String check = "";
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        /*---------------------------------------------Check for Open slot-----------------------------------------------*/
        if (array[i] == null) {
            arrIsOpen = true;
        }
        if (arrIsOpen == true) {
            array[i] = item;
            break;
        }
    }
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (arrIsOpen == true) { //Insert Sort here

        for (parseOne = 1; parseOne < (reaLen); parseOne++) {
            check = array[parseOne];
            if (check == null) {
                check = "0";
            }

            parseTwo = parseOne - 1;
            while (parseTwo >= 0 && ((check.compareTo(array[parseTwo]) < 0))) {
                array[parseTwo + 1] = array[parseTwo];
                parseTwo--;
            }
            array[parseTwo + 1] = check;
        }
    }
    else {                  // Grow the array by factor of 2 and copy over elements
        String[] backingArray = new String[2 * array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            backingArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------Sort--------------------*/
        reaLen = backingArray.length;
        for (parseOne = 1; parseOne < (reaLen); parseOne++) {
            check = array[parseOne];


            parseTwo = parseOne - 1;
            while (parseTwo >= 0 && (check.compareTo(array[parseTwo]) < 0)) {

                array[parseTwo + 1] = array[parseTwo];
                parseTwo--;
            }
            array[parseTwo + 1] = check;
        }
    }

    //assuming that the item was inserted by now
    //arrayContentCount++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: array with content 0 is sorted, no need to parseOne and parseTwo
 just put the element in the array.
You have to check that your content is atleast of count 2 to start comparing

see edited answer

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. Yes that would make sense but my teacher insisted on placing variable item in the array using insertion sort. I just don't see how you are supposed to sort an empty array

Comment: you are not supposed to sort it, if you know it is empty just put the item in, it is a special case.

Comment: Ok thank you. I maybe misinterpreted my assignment. I have class in 45 so I will ask  him then and update my post as appropriate